# For an ID, how to calculate percentage of a chosen option?

Tags: r, group-by, percentage

I was writing some code in R and for an ID I need to calculate the percentage that an option is chosen, as shown in the screenshot here:

[image: Tables]

I tried with `group_by` and the truth is that nothing has helped me.

I'm still getting started, in case you know if there is any other command or function that I can use?

I would really appreciate the help, thanks for reading!

Comment: I have to go from the table on the left to the table on the right

Answer (score 2):

Use the count function and mutate proportions as below:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  count(ID, Select) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(prop = prop.table(n)) %>% 
  select(!n)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID Select  prop
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1      1 0.667
2     1      3 0.333
3     2      1 0.2  
4     2      2 0.6  
5     2      4 0.2
```

Comment: Hii, thanks for the idea, but I have a problem that said:
"Error in select(., !n) : unused argument (!n)"

Do you know what this is about?

Comment: You would have loaded some other package like `MASS` after loading `dplyr`. The `select()` function in `dplyr` is masked by the other package.  Load `dplyr` package again and try.